# ChartJs Pointstyle Image only rendered on hover

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I am using image as **pointStyle** in line graph (datasets is in x,y coordinate) using **chartjs** in angular application.
Image is rendered successfully **once** **hovered**. I wish to render image as soon as graph is loaded.

Here is my piece of code.

```
let yourImageRed = new Image();
    yourImageRed.src = 'abc.png';


new Chart('top-chart', {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        datasets:[
           {
              data:[
                   {x:1,y:1},{x:3,y:4}
              ],
              pointStyle:yourImageRed,
              fill:false,
              spanGaps:false,
              showLines: false,
              borderWidth: 0,
              borderColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
           }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        elements: {
          point: {
            radius: 4,
            hitRadius: 0,
            hoverRadius: 0
          }
        }
    }});
```

Comment: did you have manage to solve this I'm having the same issue?

Comment: try this: 
hover: {
          animationDuration: 0
        }
and this...
elements: {
          point: {
            radius: 3,
            hitRadius: 0,
            hoverRadius: 0
          }
        }

inside options...

Comment: Also, I am using beforeInit lifeCycle in plugins for creating dataSets...